# Why was Chanah called an "Ishah Kesheirah"?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, samuel-shmuel-book-of, prophecies, chanah

The Gemoro says that when Chanah was caught by Eli davening and whispering, he asked the Urim Vetumim about her to see if she was ok. The letters **ה ר ש כ** appeared on the Urim Vetumim.

Eli understood this to be drunkard, Shikorah, yet Hashem told him to read it as Kesheirah. Why was she called this interesting term and not a more usual term like Tzadeikes or perhaps Neviah.

Comment: You could improve this question by citing the gemara in question, by indicating why "Tzadeikes" or "Neviah" would be more normal or expected than "Kesheirah" in this sort of situation, and by translating these terms, as you understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard in the name of the Chida - that women have three special Mitzvos - which is the Roshei Teivos of Chana - Ches = Chalah, Nun = Nidah, Hei = Hadlokas HaNer - and a woman who does these three is considered a Isha Ksheirah.

Notwithstanding the above there is a Medrash Breishis Rabsi Parshas Chaya Sara 23:1 which lists 22 Isha Ksheiras and one of them is Chana.

> כ"ב נשים כשרות היו בעולם ואלו הן שרה, רבקה, רחל, לאה, סרח בת אשר,
>   יוכבד, מרים, בתיה בת פרעה, דבורה, צללפונית אשת מנוח, חנה, אביגיל,
>   מיכל, בת שבע, אבישג, חולדה הנביאה, יעל, אסתר.‏

Comment: +1 although this really just amplifies the question even more.

Comment: Can anyone think of any positive female characters in Tanach that are not listed?

Comment: The Medrash says there were 22, however only lists 18!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/medrash-breishis-rabsi-parshas-chaya-sara-231-which-lists-22-isha-ksheiras

Comment: If a woman is considered kesheirah for keeping nidah, chalah and hadlakas haner, and Rachel is an ishah kesheirah, why did she die during childbirth? The mishnah at the end of Bameh Madlikin says "For three sins women die during childbirth..."

Comment: @ ba - that can be asked as a Seperate question. However by Rachel there was a curse uttered by Yaakov and other factors involved.

Comment: Can you source this Chida? The Chida is really the main part of the answer; the midrash just shows an example whereas the OP looked for a reason.

Comment: My friend told me it is in [Tzavorei Shallal](http://hebrewbooks.org/37712). I do not know yet where in the Sefer it is.

Comment: Thanks all for your help! Let us not forget that the Midrash that an Isha Kesheirah is someone who fulfills the wish of her husband!

Comment: @Yehuda Can you cite that midrash?

Comment: @DoubleAA it is a Pirkei DeRebbi Eliezer somewhere, looking for it!

Comment: אין לך אשה כשרה בנשים אלא אשה שהיא עושה רצון בעלה (ילקוט שמעוני שופטים רמז מב)

Comment: Why is it "Hadlakat haNer" but not "Hafrashat Challah"? In one case we take the acronym from the object and in the other we take it from the appended verb.

Answer (score 3):

The word כשרה can also be read כְּשָׂרָה — "like Sarah" — perhaps reflecting that they were both childless, praying to have children.

Comment: nice one, is that your own?

Comment: I saw it somewhere, but I don't remember where.

Comment: I've heard that too somewhere.

Comment: This site quotes it in the name of the Gra http://torah.org/learning/yomtov/roshhashanah/vol13no6.html

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/criteria-for-the-list-of-nashim-kesheiros-medrash-breishis-rabsi/28265#28265