# Criteria for the list of Nashim Kesheiros (Medrash Breishis Rabsi)

Tags: number, women, midrash, tzaddikim

The Medrash Breishis Rabsi Parshas Chaya Sara 23:1 lists 22* Nashim Kesheiros.

כ"ב נשים כשרות היו בעולם ואלו הן שרה, רבקה, רחל, לאה, סרח בת אשר, יוכבד, מרים, בתיה בת פרעה, דבורה, צללפונית אשת מנוח, חנה, אביגיל, מיכל, בת שבע, אבישג, חולדה הנביאה, יעל, אסתר.‏

What criteria does the Medrash use to decide who is an Isha Ksheira?

{*Note: Although the Medrash says there are 22, there are only 18 listed.}

Comment: **בראשית** רבתי **פרשת חיי שרה** עמוד 100
**[כג, א]** > מדרש משלי (בובר) פרשה לא